# angularjs ng-pattern regex for 4 digits and 2 decimal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I am trying to create a Regex for a number with maximum 4 digits and if the input has decimal it has to have 2 digits - `.20` and not `.1`.
tried:

```
ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/" //fail for 666666, .10, .1
```

Examples for valid inputs:

```
100.10
100
3000.10
```

Example for invalid:

```
10000 //has more then 4 digits before decimal
100.1 //has only 1 digit after decimal
.10 //has no digits before decimal
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Use {#,#} to limit the number of digits to 1 to 4

Try

`^[0-9]{1,4}(\.[0-9][0-9])?$`

#### Use (     )? to make an optional two-digit decimal part

The problem with using the {1,2} is that it allows one or two digits, when you really only want two. And I assume you want to enforce a rule that *if* they have a ".", they must have two digits?

#### For example

```
var patt = /^[0-9]{1,4}(\.[0-9][0-9])?$/i

"1011.11".match(patt)!==null
"1011.1".match(patt)!==null
```

Returns

```
true
false
```

#### With gratitude to Sebastian Proske and Wiktor Stribiżew

For pointing out the need to escape the `.`

Comment: Parsing error - angular.min.js:123 Error: [$parse:lexerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.3/$parse/lexerr?p0=Unexpected%20next%20char…=s%200-0%20%5B%5E%5D&p2=%5E%5B0-9%5D%7B1%2C4%7D(.%5B0-9%5D%5B0-9%5D)%3F%24

Comment: Really strange. How about just in a browser?

Comment: well for ng-pattern the format is `ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{1,4}(.[0-9][0-9])?$/g"` so it works great. thanks.

Comment: @SebastianProske just tested `1a22` with ng-pattern and it was invalid as expected.

Comment: Ah yes thanks Sebastian. Its a nasty feature of regex that in different versions, the parentheses, dots etc have to be escaped or not escaped. Sorry. I will add to answer. Turns out (by chance!) that I got it right for Itsik's case but your point is important for others.

Comment: A literal dot should be escaped outside a character class/bracket expression in *every* regex flavor. Even in POSIX.

Comment: Yes I have just realised this Wiktor. Thanks. Parentheses are variable in needing escapes though. I hate regex. But also I love regex!